# Magento customer login hanging for some accounts

Tags: magento, authentication

More and more customers have problems logging in to our site

As you can see the connection gets reset after a while.

We run Magento Enterprise v 1.14.1.0

Please help with this! Trying to debug this for a couple of days with no luck

EDIT:

This is only happening for a small amount of the customers which is why it is hard to debug.

EDIT 2:

Turned of varnish cache and it didn't help.

Comment: Are you using any full page caching extension apart from Magento enterprise full page caching.?

Comment: We use varnish cache but disabled full page caching

Comment: Can you try after disabling the varnish cache for the customer login page? Because in Magento 1.14.1.0 we have form keys in frontend forms also. So in you case when the login form is served the form key values may be coming from cache.So it may not be unique key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just need to figure out how to do that. It has been set up by a senior developer. I turned of the module and it crashed the whole site. But if that would be the problem shouldnt all customers have problems logging in?

Comment: That might be a problem on your server. It might be running out of memory, try adding more memory or extending the request time out limit. If what I said is correct, try to find the module/code/script that is consuming your server memory

Comment: Perseusi thank you for your answer. This is only related to certain accounts, I mean if there is a memory leak it, this should happen to all accounts right?

Comment: @Nino10 : Have you got the solution ?